# Product price calculation on order emails and pdfs

Tags: price, catalog-price-rules, pdf, order-email

I have a client that needs to increase product prices using catalog price rules.

Unfortunately Magento shortsightedly `min()` the catalog price rules wherever they are found.  I managed to change this functionality everywhere EXCEPT the order confirmation emails/pdfs.  Does anyone know where those product prices are pulled from and the catalog price rules applied at?

### I've changed:

#### file: app/code/core/Mage/Weee/Model/Mysql4/Tax.php

change:

```
‘value’ => 100-max(0, min(100, $row[’action_amount’])),
```

to:

```
 ‘value’ => 100-$row[’action_amount’],
```

#### file: app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Price.php

change:

```
$finalPrice = min($finalPrice, $rulePrice);
```

to:

```
$finalPrice = $rulePrice;
```

#### file: app/code/core/Mage/CatalogRule/Model/Observer.php

change (2x):

```
$finalPrice = min($product->getData(’final_price’), $this->_rulePrices[$key]);
```

to:

```
$finalPrice = $this->_rulePrices[$key];
```

Like I said this is working on the frontend and the admin, everywhere as far as I can tell EXCEPT the order email/pdfs, so I'm thinking that these are calculated in yet another location that I have yet to identify.